# Returning most used Letters while Looping - Python

Tags: python-3.x

How can I return the letter that is used the most in the for loop ?

My Code:

```
import string

def intefer_shift(encrypted_textfile, language):

index = 0
file_connector = open(encrypted_textfile,'r')
data = file_connector.read()
box =[]
data = data.lower()

file_connector.close()
times = 0

#this for loop is designed to count the number of times items appear in file

#   this for loop is designed print each letter in the alphabet and tells how many times they appear
for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
    num = data.count(letter)
    print(letter, ':', num)

intefer_shift('homework1.txt','English')
```

Comment: Your question is entirely code, please can you actually ask a *question* in your **question**.

Comment: Do you know how dictionaries work? If yes, use one to count the letters. The modern way to count something is the [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Answer (score 0):

Simply add some kind of counter to store max_value, updated (if necessary) at every iteration of the loop.

```
top_letter = None
max_count = 0
for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
    num = data.count(letter)
    print(letter, ':', num)
    if num > max_count:
        max_count = num
        top_letter = letter
return top_letter
```

Mind the fact, that counting letters in probably big data-string one after another might be not efficient, and probably better option would be to loop all of the letters in data once and increment counter for each of them (this solution has worse space complexity, but better time complexity).